# Laravel - How to redirect to a desired page when user is not authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to use the `__constructor` from the extended class (`AdminController` extends `AdminBaseController`) but aparently it's not working and I have no idea of what can be, here you can see both of my classes:

AdminBaseController.php

```
class AdminBaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        if (!Auth::user()){
            return view('admin.pages.login.index');
        }
    }
}
```

AdminController.php

```
class AdminController extends AdminBaseController
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.index');
    }

    public function ajuda()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.admin.ajuda');
    }
}
```

### EDIT

---

This is my `admin` route group:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@index');

    Route::get('login', 'Admin\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Admin\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('logout', 'Admin\AuthController@getLogout');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'configuracoes'], function () {
        Route::get('geral', 'Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController@geral');
        Route::get('social', 'Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController@social');
        Route::get('analytics', 'Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController@analytics');
    });

    Route::get('ajuda', 'Admin\AdminController@ajuda');
});
```

Comment: you don't do anything inside AdminController::construct() so you can avoid to write it and the class will use his parent constructor. From the question it's not clear: what is the problem ?

Comment: @Moppo I have a lot of controllers for the admin area, and to avoid code repeat I was thinking in verify if the user is auth with the __constructor inside `AdminBaseController`

Comment: ok. You should use a middleware to check if the user is an admin

Comment: i've posted an answer explaining how to use a middleware

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The controller is not the right place to check if a user is authenticated or not. You should use a middleware for that. To get info on what a middleware is check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

Let's see how you can use the default Laravel's `auth` middleware for this purpose:

First of all get rid of your `AdminBaseController` and use only `AdminController`

Then you have to check that the `auth` middleware is enabled in the file `app\Http\Kernel.php`

You should have the line:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

This means that the middleware is active and usable for your routes.

Now let's go inside the middleware class in `app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php` to specify the middleware's behaviour  :

```
//this method will be triggered before your controller constructor
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check here if the user is authenticated
    if ( ! $this->auth->user() )
    {
        // here you should redirect to login 
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now the only thing left to do is to decide for what routes you should apply the middleware. Let's suppose you have two routes that you want to be only accessible from authenticated users, you should specify to use the middleware for these two routes in this way:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function()
{
    Route::get('admin/index', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('admin/ajuda', 'AdminController@ajuda');
});
```

Comment: little problem found, after implement this when i submit the form it just, reflesh the page...

Comment: The problem is: The postLogin is entering inside the middleware too, because it is inside the admin group, I edit my answer to show you my routes

Comment: I've solved the problem removing the `admin/login` route from the `admin` route, is this the right way?

Comment: exactly: the postLogin shoulb be outside the authenticated routes group because the user it not still authenticate when the form is submitted

Comment: THANK YOU!! This was the correct solution in laravel.

Answer (score 4):

Use middleware for this purpose and then in controller constructor use it as in example below.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

And then you need to secure routes where you want from user to be logged in to access.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
      Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
});
```

Comment: I'm totally noob into php/laravel and have never used middlewares by my self, looking into the files I can see a middleware called `Authenticate` and inside it a function called `handle`, may can I use it?

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.5 , an unauthenticated user will cause the Authenticate middleware to throw a `AuthenticationException` exception.

```
protected function authenticate(array $guards)
{
 if (empty($guards))
 {
  return $this->auth->authenticate();
 }
 foreach ($guards as $guard) {
  if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
      return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
  }
 }
 throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);
}
```

This will be caught by the app/Exceptions/Handler class which will call its `render` method which is responsible for converting a given exception into a HTTP response.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
 return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

App/Exceptions/Handler extends 'Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler', located inside '/vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler'. It has its own render method. Within that render method, there's a `if else` statement that says.

```
elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException)
{
 return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
}
```

Below is the ‘unauthenticated‘ method that is called by the above within the same class

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
  return $request->expectsJson() ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401) : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

within this method is where you redirect an unauthenticated user.

As far as I can see, this is what goes on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The way you extends and execute the parent constrictor is right, however
returning a  view to execute it is only possible from routes, controller actions and filters. Otherwise you have to call send().

for you purpose I think you should use before for filter http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Comment: Yeah as Denis saide middleware is also the great wait to go in laravel5