# Laravel redirect issue from blade template

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I am new in laravel 5 .
I am working on larvel page security and i have to prevent open some page or Url 
but when i use `{{ Redirect::to('/dashboard') }}` in view it is not working .

Please help me to find a way to `use Redirect / Url` in laravel view (Blade template)

I have already tried :-

1. `{{ url('/dashboard') }}`
2. `{{ Redirect::to('/dashboard') }}`

Code :-

```
@if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
{{ 'Page' }}
@else 
{{ Redirect::to('/dashboard') }}
@endif
```

Comment: have you checked laravel's redirect function

Comment: Yes but they are only for controller ..

Comment: Can you please show some more clarity with code? exactly need to confirm if it reached till the code or not. Because there is no error mentioned, you are getting any error ? or just happens nothing?

Comment: I have added my code please check

Comment: Ah, I see, so you are trying to redirect the user when is on the view right?

Comment: are you sure that the role_id is an Integer? Or try to put else in the if condition instead just to test.

Comment: please try (Auth::user()->role_id == "1")

Comment: Thanks @AjitHogade but that is not issue ..

Comment: @AmanKumar check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089905/laravel-how-to-redirect-to-login-if-user-is-not-authenticated the same logic applies to check is a user has `role_id == 1`

Comment: @Nicolas +1, this is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a JavaScript redirect instead:

```
@if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
  {{ 'Page' }}
@else 
  <script>window.location = "/dashboard";</script>
@endif
```

Comment: What if you need to return a message as well?  using `with()`?

Comment: What will happen if user disabled javascript in browser

Answer (score 14):

```
@if(your conditions)
    @php
        header("Location: " . URL::to('/'), true, 302);
        exit();
    @endphp
@endif
```

Comment: Please elaborate why this is the answer, so this helps OP in the future

Comment: @TimStack 
When you use JavaScript to redirect, You have to load the first page and then redirect it with JavaScript. This has two problems: 1- The user may have blocked permission to JavaScript from the browser. So, the redirect will not be successful. 2- This redirect method is not the right thing to do in terms of SEO.
But if redirection is managed on the server-side, there is no need to load the first page. So, the above problems will not occur.

Comment: Please amend your post. Don't put extra information in a comment. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Your question is hard to understand, but I suppose you want to redirect the user on the view after check if he is login. I have bad news for you, logic goes on the **Controller** not on **Views**.

That means you need to check if the user is login on the **Controller** and after that you redirect to the proper view, on Laravel the most common way to do it is to create a **Middleware** that checks if the user is login and then apply the correct logic.

You have a lot of ways to do it, but at first you need  to understand how it works, you can check it on the [Laravel Authentication docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)

Comment: Please check my question i want to add redirect into my view (blade template) according to condition as shown in my question

Comment: No i just check  condition role in view and wants to redirect on some error page using redirect  in view

Comment: @AmanKumar as I said on my answer this type of logic must be on a Middleware/Controller, not in the view.

Comment: @AmanKumar This is the best way to do this. If you need to check if someone is logged in or not and redirect it's best done in the Controller, Middleware, or even in the routes file but not in the view. To Use Redirect::to() you have to return that which won't work in the view since it's loading the page for the user already. Message me on Twitter if you want some help with the code... vmitchell85

Answer (score 5):

Use route path with Javascript redirect:

```
  @if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
      {{ 'Page' }}
   @else 
      <script>window.location = "{{ route('admin.list') }}";</script>
      <?php exit; ?>
   @endif
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@if(put_your_condition_here)
  {{session(['must_login'=>'must_login'])}};//if you want to display flash message
 window.location.href = "{{url('put your route here')}}";
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create this redirect using Javascript

```
@if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
  {{ 'Page' }}
@else 
  <script>
    window.location = "/dashboard";
  </script>
@endif
```