# How to implement Laravel Auth to redirect users?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, url, routes

I am working with `vue 3` and `laravel` and want to make certain urls in the admin dashboard unaccessible for users that are not logged in. The user can visit `domain/admin` url to find the `login form`. Once the correct credentials are entered, the user gets redirected to the `/dashboard` and has access to all other backend urls.

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089905/laravel-how-to-redirect-to-a-desired-page-when-user-is-not-authenticated) and am trying to implement the accepted answer.

My **`web.php`** looks like this:

```
// HTTPS REQUEST
Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login']);

//BACKEND REDIRECTS
Route::any('/admin', function () {
    return view('cms');
})->name('admin');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::any('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('cms');
    })->name('dashboard');

    Route::any('/dashboard/artwork', function () {
        return view('cms');
    })->name('artwork');

    Route::any('/dashboard/artwork/upload', function () {
        return view('cms');
    })->name('artwork-upload');

    Route::any('/dashboard/blog', function () {
        return view('cms');
    })->name('blog');

    Route::any('/dashboard/blog/compose', function () {
        return view('cms');
    })->name('blog-compose');

    Route::any('/dashboard/newsletter', function () {
        return view('cms');
    })->name('newsletter-cms');

    Route::any('/dashboard/newsletter/compose', function () {
        return view('cms');
    })->name('newsletter-compose');
});
```

And I have added this function to `Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check here if the user is authenticated
    if ( ! $this->auth->user() )
    {
        // here you should redirect to login
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to proceed. Inside `Authenticate.php`:

1. How do I check if the user is authenticated?
2. How do I redirect to login? That would be `/admin` url in my case.
3. PhpStorm marks `$next` in `return $next($request);` as an error and shows:

   `Function name must be callable - a string, Closure or class implementing '__invoke', currently '\App\Http\Middleware\Closure'`

Right now, when I try to open `/dashboard` the log shows this:

```
[2022-03-10 17:10:00] local.ERROR: Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, App\Http\Middleware\Closure $next) must be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Declaration of App\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate::handle($request, App\\Http\\Middleware\\Closure $next) must be compatible with Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) at /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php:22)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the Auth facade

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Then you can change it to this

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Also, I usually prefer to add middleware using the CLI
`php artisan make:middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated`

Then you can add

`auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class`

to the `$routeMiddleware` array in the `App\Http\Kernel.php` file

And finally, run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The `$next` function name is still not resolved. Any idea on that?